# How can I create an iOS-style toolbar in my Mac Cocoa application?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ios, macos, uitabbar

Several iLife '11 applications on the Mac use iOS-style black toolbars. For instance, the toolbar at the bottom of this screenshot of iPhoto:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pocket-lint.com](http://www.pocket-lint.com/images/dynamic/3190f503c8d45d59bcd773f56145c7646a659536.jpg))</sub>

This sort of look is available in the iOS SDK as "UITabBar."

I am wondering if there is an easy way to achieve this in my ordinary, non-iOS Mac application. If not, what would be the best way to go about creating this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that will give you this view out of the box. You'll need to build it yourself.

The simplest method would be to create a custom view with a gradient background and place monochrome buttons in it.

Better would be to create a set of classes similar to `NSToolBar` that handle positioning, highlighting etc. Even better, build it and then open-source it :-)

However, you'll have to build it yourself. Apart from `NSButton` there's not much that will help in the pre-existing objects.